# Definition of $\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I have previously seen that $\mathbb{Q}(\theta) = ${$a+b\sqrt\theta:a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$}.

But I saw an example $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})=${$a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{4} : a,b,c\in\mathbb{Q}$}.

I was wondering what is the general rule here for when we define these structures.

Comment: Yes: if the order of the radical is $r$, a basis is  all powers of  $\sqrt[r]{a^k}$ $\:(0\le k<r)$.

Comment: I have **never** seen

Comment: If $R$ is a ring, usually, one denotes by $R[\theta]$ the ring of polynomials in $\theta$ and by $R(\theta)$ its fraction field, the ring of rational functions in $\theta$. In the case that $R$ is a field and $\theta$ is algebraic over $R$, then $R[\theta]=R(\theta)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\theta$ be an algebraic number and $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ its minimal polynomial. Suppose $\deg(f)=n$: then $1, \theta,...,\theta^{n-1}$ form a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$.

In your case $x^3-2$ is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{2}$ and a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is given by $1, \sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{2}^2=\sqrt[3]{4}$.

Comment: I have **never** seen $Q(\theta)$ as meaning $\{a+ b\sqrt{\theta}| a,b\in Q\}$.  I would expect that to be represented by $Q(\sqrt{\theta}))$.

Comment: I didn't notice it in the question: I think it might be a typo